# How to horizontally align heading and navbar?

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar, I have a heading. My problem occurs when I attempt to place my heading on the same "line" of my navbar if that makes sense, originally, when I place my h2 element, the text would appear above the navbar.

When I fix the h2 element, it will be left aligned and overlapping my navbar, even though I specified it to be centered in the HTML. Can somebody please explain what makes a webpage do this? And why fixed elements cannot be moved around (Left aligned, centered, right aligned etc.)

I don't know if my container is the issue, my container will be the basic, well "container" for all the information that will be displayed in this page.

Finally, I am new to HTML and any information will be useful in the long run. Thank you.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vjzmqdxk/)

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
}
.logo {
  margin-left: 25px;
}
.navbar {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  float: left;
}
h2 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-size: 35px;
  position: fixed;
}
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 175px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 2px solid #555;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 12px 0 12px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
li {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}
li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepage.css">
  <title>CSGOMarble</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h3 style="float: right; margin-right: 25px;">
    <a href="http://www.steamcommunity.com/login/">SIGN IN WITH STEAM</a>
  </h3>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="LOGO" height="60px" width="200px">
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="container">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Welcome to CSGOMarble!</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li style="background-color: #D9D9D9; font-size: 20px; padding: 12px 0 12px 0;">MENU</li>
      <li><a href="coinflip.html">COINFLIP</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When you fix an element, it takes the element out of the flow of the document (or DOM) and ends up in the "0 0" position of the current context (either the body or the closest parent container with a `position` of `relative`. If there is an element occupying that position (such as your nav) in the document, the fixed element will overlap it if not positioned otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the spec on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

> **`position:fixed`** Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it when scrolled. When printing, position it at that fixed position on every page. This value always create a new stacking context.

So you should not use that for placing two elements side by side. Instead you could use float, inline block, flexbox etc. Here is an example of `float`:

```
.navbar {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.container {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vjzmqdxk/2/)

**Edit:** In order to center the heading, you could use CSS3 `calc()`,  updated code below.

```
.navbar {
  float: left;
  width: 175px;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
.container {
  float: right;
  width: calc(100% - 200px); /*175+25=200*/
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vjzmqdxk/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do, is give both the `h2` and the `navbar` `display:inline-block;`. No need for `position:fixed;`. Also rearrange the HTML so the navbar is before the h2.

https://jsfiddle.net/muor36cv/

Comment: As mentioned above, the content of h2 is no longer centered? Why is this? Thank you.

Comment: This is because the h2's width is being shrunk to the remainder of the space taken up by the navbar. It is still centered, just the h2's width is not as large as it was before.